# Windows doesn't recognize Nexus 7 in recovery mode

Tags: adb, nexus-7, recovery-mode, windows

So I have the Nexus 7 (2012). When the tablet is on and USB debugging is enabled, ADB recognizes it. But when I shut it off and put it into recovery mode, then press power and volume up to sideload, Windows/ADB does not recognize it. If I navigate to `usb_driver` it says it can't find a driver there. I'm trying to update it to KitKat using the OTA update.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue to me.

Comment: why does it work when the tablet is on?

Comment: I think it uses different driver in fastboot mode normal mode and recovery mode.

Comment: well recovery mode uses the adb driver, and when its on it should also be using the adb driver. Anyways i might of fixed it, i force installed the adb interface driver to it. Now it is recognized in command prompt adb

Comment: The device is presenting itself using different device-IDs, depending on the mode (normal/recovery/fastboot) used. I guess that's what roxan was pointing to. Being a Linux user, I'm not sure how Windows deals with this (different driver, or same driver with different parameters, or something completely different).

Comment: Being a recently Windows converted user I can say that it asks driver for each and every step.

Comment: related: [Android 5.0 Lollipop device not detected via USB](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb)

Comment: Use this link [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb] to install the Google USB drivers. All other solutions mentioned here are outdated and do not work for Windows 10.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're missing the adb recovery driver. You might consider trying Koush's [universal USB driver installer](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH) -- it solved this very problem by installing the missing drivers.

Comment: Does not work for Windows 10. See my comment to original post.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Nexus 5. Windows 8.1 and adb recognized the device until I put it in recovery mode, then it disappeared. I finally said "let me pick from a list of device drivers" and chose the "Android Composite ADB interface." Then adb recognized it and I was able to sideload an update.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent way too many hours trying to fix this same problem when trying to sideload onto my Nexus 6.

What finally worked for me:

- Apply update from ADB in the recovery menu.
- Once the phone was waiting for the files

  - I unplugged the phone from USB
  - then re-plugged it back into the computer.
- Then it was there in the device manager and when I did a device check through adb on my console
- I ran the adb sideload command and it is currently optimizing my apps

Hope this helps anyone having this problem on their nexus devices.

Comment: Does not work for Windows 10. See my comment to original post.